# difference between ghostscript and ghost4j

Tags: ghostscript, ghost4j

i want to repring pdf files in Java application.

I found that ghostscript has Java library - ghost4j.

Do you have any experience with it - is ghost4j is as good as ghostscript ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ghostscript does **not** have a Java library.

Ghost4J is a wrapper around Ghostscript (written in C) which makes it accessible from Java. This is not supplied nor supported by Artifex and is not part of 'Ghostscript', its an addition by a 3rd party developer.

That said, since it actually uses Ghostscript, it is potentially 'as good as Ghostscript', but it may well not expose the entire set of functionality.